# How to set different thumbnail size for Woocommerce category and products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My shop page displays categories. I need the category thumbnail to be 100px wide. When I'm changing the width in Customizer it changes product thumbnail size as well, but it has to be 380px wide. 
I tried to look for those separate values in Woocommerce settings, but it says that the product display settings are in Customizer and I'm stuck there. I couldn't find anything in Woocommerce templates as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code?  If you are not writing any code, but rather just using the GUI in WordPress Customizer, then Stack Overflow is not the right forum for this question. Good luck!

Comment: I'm building my theme and I'm just starting with woocommerce. I don't know where to set different thumbnail sizes for categories and products as I can't find it anywhere in woocommerce template files. I tried to Google it and there were hints that I can change it in Customizer but it does not separate the sizes.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear, you are not writing any code?